# Why is fetch from ASP.NET Cache slower that fetch from dabase on high load

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, caching

I am runing WebForms application on IIS7.5 and I wanted to improve application performance by caching lookup values instead of getting those values from datase each time page is loaded.

I used `Cache` class and fetched data using
`value=Cache["key"];` .
But instead of improving performance i degraded them on heavy load.
When I tested application with one user  everything was fine. I took less then 1ms to fetch data from cache. When I simulated 80 concurrent users it took in average 500ms to fetch data from cache and at the same time same amount of data is fetched from database for around 20ms. So fetching from memory is more that 20 times slower that fetching from database.
Database is located on separate server.
I tested this on three different servers and fetching from memory is always slower.
I also used `Glav.CacheAdapter` to bypass ASP.Net cache and I got the same results, even worse.

Is the any logical explanation why is fetching from cache slower than fetching from database on heavy load?

**UPDATE:** It seams that slow reading from cache is not result of hi load. Using JMeter to simulate users cause this.
If I run one request using JMeter it takes more that 100ms to get data from cache, and if I run the same request using browser it takes less than 1ms to fetch the same data.
Not sure why JMeter is causing this.

Comment: Are you sure that the cache didn't expire your items?

Comment: Under the heavy load interval, did you try monitoring the OS and IIS free resources (memory and CPU)?

Comment: @spender Cache was valid for next hour and I confirmed in debug mode that data is stored in the cache when fetched

Comment: @kayess More that half available memory was free during the test but CPU was on hi load constantly 80-100%